# ALSA lib pcm.c:8568:(snd_pcm_recover) underrun occurred

Tags: pyttsx3

I have this code:

```py
import pyttsx3

engine = pyttsx3.init()
voices = engine.getProperty('voices')

engine.setProperty('voice', voices[0].id)

newVoiceRate = 200
engine.setProperty('rate', newVoiceRate)

def speak(audio):
    engine.say(audio)
    engine.runAndWait()

speak("hello this is a program")
```

and these errors:

> ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1032:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
> ALSA lib pcm.c:2664:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.rear
> ALSA lib pcm.c:2664:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.center_lfe
> ALSA lib pcm.c:2664:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.side
> ALSA lib pcm_route.c:877:(find_matching_chmap) Found no matching channel map
> Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
> Cannot connect to server request channel
> jack server is not running or cannot be started
> JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
> JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
> Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
> Cannot connect to server request channel
> jack server is not running or cannot be started
> JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
> JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
> ALSA lib pcm_oss.c:397:(_snd_pcm_oss_open) Cannot open device /dev/dsp
> ALSA lib pcm_oss.c:397:(_snd_pcm_oss_open) Cannot open device /dev/dsp
> ALSA lib pcm_a52.c:1001:(_snd_pcm_a52_open) a52 is only for playback
> ALSA lib confmisc.c:160:(snd_config_get_card) Invalid field card
> ALSA lib pcm_usb_stream.c:482:(_snd_pcm_usb_stream_open) Invalid card 'card'
> ALSA lib confmisc.c:160:(snd_config_get_card) Invalid field card
> ALSA lib pcm_usb_stream.c:482:(_snd_pcm_usb_stream_open) Invalid card 'card'
> ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1032:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
> Cannot connect to server socket err = No existe el fichero o el directorio
> Cannot connect to server request channel
> jack server is not running or cannot be started
> JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
> JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
> ALSA lib pcm.c:8568:(snd_pcm_recover) underrun occurred
>
> Process finished with exit code 0

My *OS* is **Manjaro** :)